# How to add an onclick event to a dynamic generated div

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a number of `div`s in my HTML file that are dynamically generated. When I add the `div`s, I want to add an `onclick` event to each `div`.

Each `div` has a dynamic `id`. Using `id`, how can add an `onclick` handler?

Code that generates `div`s:

```
function createSlider(resp) {
    $.each(resp, function(key, val) {
        var item = "<div class='item' id="+val.id+">";

        item += "<h2>" + val.category + "</h2>";
        item += "<img src=" + val.image + " alt=" + val.title + ">";
        item += "</div>";

        $(".content-conveyor").append(item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply the click function to the ID after you append it to the dom. So, after your `$(".content-conveyor").append(item);` line, add this:

```
$('#' + val.id).click(function() {
// Do stuff on click
});
```

---

**Edit:** After thinking about it more and considering @Nemoden's answer, you could also do it like this:

```
function createSlider(resp) {
    $.each(resp, function(key, val) {
        var item = "<div class='item' id="+val.id+">";

        item += "<h2>" + val.category + "</h2>";
        item += "<img src=" + val.image + " alt=" + val.title + ">";
        item += "</div>";
        var $item = $(item).click(function() {
            // Add on click code here
        });
        $(".content-conveyor").append($item);
    });
}
```

This would attach the click callback without having to use the ID at all.

Comment: That's an assumption made based on the OP's code. They assign that value to the ID of their new div so I think it's a safe assumption.

Comment: That wasn't criticism of the answer (that's my vote), just commentary/musing out load.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks! [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/PhA8U/1/) the same thing with the edited code. **Edit** Beat me to it.

Comment: Too bad @Nemoden might not have seen it.

Comment: Thanks for the code, and what to do if i want click event on image that is inside div

Comment: @Romi Well, in my first example, you can use `$('#' + val.id + ' img').click(...` Or, in the second example, you could use `var $item = $(item).find('img').click(...`. Note the space in between the quote and `img` in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the class name of the div for an event handler on all elements that match that class name.

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    //
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**.live()** is used to attach handlers to DOM elements that may not yet exist in the DOM. 
 After  `$(".content-conveyor").append($item);`  add following code.

```
 $('#' + val.id).live(click,function() {
 // your code here
 });
```

Comment: If you stop and think about `.live()` and how it's used, it doesn't really make a lot of sense when using an `id` selector in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps `$('.content-conveyor div').live(...` would be better but that depends on the user's code.

Comment: .live() is now deprecated and removed as of jQuery 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed