# On click function for a 'a href' button is not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, onclick, event-handling

I have some HTML that is functioning as a link button to another page:

```
<a href="#breakdownDialog" class="ui-btn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" id="cvResults"> 
  <h3>First Name</h3>   
  <span>87%</span>
</a>
```

Note that this is a single-html file JQuery Mobile site, so the `#breakdownDialog` takes the user to another page.

I have tried to create a function that adds some table elements into the `breakdownDialog` page, which references a resultsJSONClient object which has previously been passed in from the server side:

```
$('#cvResults').click(function(e) {
$('#cvResultsDialog h3').text(resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id);
console.log("json profile"+resultsJSONClient.profile_json);
$('#dialogContent').append(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<resultsJSONClient.profile_json.length; i++){
            return '<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing ="0" width="100%" style="border: 4px solid transparent;"><tr id="'+ 
            resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].title+'"><td>'+
            resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id+'</td><td align="right">'+
            resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].value+'</td></tr>';
            console.log(resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id);
        }
});    
});
```

I'm sure there are numerous errors with that code, which I am happy to debug, but I'm mainly concerned with getting the onClick event to fire in the first place. I put in some diagnostic `console.log`s and these aren't displaying, which must mean the function isn't triggering. Is there a reason why this isn't happening? I have tried numerous variations of the `onClick` JQuery methods.

Thanks
**EDIT:** The `resultsJSONClient` object is (I've cut some values out for brevity):

```
{ title: 'Name here',
  percentage: 63.2,
  profile_json:
   [ { id: 'Big 5', title: true, value: '' },
 { id: 'Openness', title: true, value: '100%' },
 { id: 'Adventurousness', title: false, value: '98%' },
 { id: 'Artistic interests', title: false, value: '64%' },
 { id: 'Emotionality', title: false, value: '8%' },
 .........]}
```

I know that this has reached the client-side, because my ajax call returns it correctly. This happens when pressing another button on the homepage:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    dataType: 'json', //datatype of argument for success function
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',//content type being sent to server 'application/json'
    data: textInput,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#resultsList').append('<a href="#breakdownDialog" class="ui-btn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" id="cvResults"> <h3>' + response.title + '</h3>   <span>' + response.percentage +
            '%</span></a>');
        console.log(response.title + response.percentage);
        var resultsJSONClient=response;
    },             
});
});
```

I was wondering if you could pass on this JSON object to the other JQuery onClick function like I have, but since my function doesn't even seem to trigger (no console.logs) I haven't reached this problem yet.
Finally, an overview of the HTML structure I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>...</title>
            <meta name="viewport" con...>       
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">         
        <script src="https.../2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/.../jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
        <script src="https:/.../jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js">    </script>              
        </head>
         <body>
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                 <img src=...>
                 <h1>R...</h1>
                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">                 
                    <id="submitForm">
                     <fieldset>
                          <textarea id="textArea" required="true" ... name="content"></textarea>
                         <button class="btn btn-block" type="submit">
                                Analyse         
                         </button>
                     </fieldset>
                      </form>

                  </div>

            <h2>Results</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="resultsList" data-inset="true">

            </ul>
            </div>      
        </div> 
        <div data-role="page" id="breakdownDialog" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" id="cvResultsDialog">
            <h3>...</span>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="dialogContent">                
        </div>
    </div>          
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfExtract.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the structure of the page containing the HTML snippet and JavaScript look like?  One thing that causes this kind of behavior is when the JS runs before the page is fully loaded, and the selector finds nothing, which fails silently.

Comment: That wold explain what I'm seeing, although I don't see how this particular JQuery could fire before the page has loaded. I've added in the HTML structure into my question. Cheers.

Comment: The fastest way to test for this is to wrap the block that registers the click handler in `$(...)`, which will delay its evaluation until the page has loaded.

If the JS is running at the toplevel of a script tag or JavaScript file, it very well could be some load-order issue.  Is the code that registers the click handler part of `pdfExtract.js`?

Comment: Another remark -- in the later HTML markup you shared, I don't see an element with ID `#cvResults`, which makes me think that ID may be set dynamically, which lends some credence to the load-order hypothesis.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean now. The `#cvResults` id tag gets added in after clicking the Analyse button (it's contained within a list that is generated). How do I deal with this? Could I add some sort of function when the list is generated that reloads the attached script?

Answer (score 1):

Think I have an answer to my own question. It's because I was dynamically generating the ID tag, so the script was loading before the tag was generated.

I solved this by including the onClick function within the function that generated the id tags, like this (there are some other errors in this script, but it solves the problem of the event not triggering):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    dataType: 'json', //datatype of argument for success function
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',//content type being sent to server 'application/json'
    data: textInput,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#resultsList').append('<a href="#breakdownDialog" data-transition="slidefade" class="ui-btn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" id="cvResults"> <h3>' + //data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" 
                response.title + 
                '</h3>   <span>' + response.percentage +
            '%</span></a>');
        console.log(response.title + response.percentage);
        var resultsJSONClient=response;

        $('#cvResults').click(function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            console.log("hello");
            $('#cvResultsDialog h3').text(resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id);
            console.log("json profile"+resultsJSONClient.profile_json);
            $('#dialogContent').append(function(){
                    for(var i=0; i<resultsJSONClient.profile_json.length; i++){
                        return '<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing ="0" width="100%" style="border: 4px solid transparent;"><tr id="'+ 
                        resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].title+'"><td>'+
                        resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id+'</td><td align="right">'+
                        resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].value+'</td></tr>';
                        console.log(resultsJSONClient.profile_json[i].id);
                    }
            });    
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){
        jQuery.error(errorThrown);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }        
});
});
```

More information here: [How to add an onclick event to a dynamic generated div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365848/how-to-add-an-onclick-event-to-a-dynamic-generated-div)

Comment: Another answer that might be cleaner, and not involve inlining the click handler, is in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050439/2718315

Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

the onclick event is triggering correctly, see : http://fiddle.jshell.net/bog500/9h8oksnv/

If you could provide a sample of resultsJSONClient we could help you

Comment: But if it's triggering why is nothing being printed to the console? I've added the JSON and some other context into the question. Thanks.